# Android.Обновление LayoutManager при смене ориентации

Tags: android, recyclerview, layoutmanager

Имеется `Activity` c `ViewPager`. В одном из `Page` есть фрагмент с `RecyclerView`.
Там я задаю и `LayoutManager` и `ScrollListener` в методе `onCreateView`. Всё хорошо.
Поставил на активити `android:configChanges="screenSize"`, для того чтобы активити не пересоздавалась при смене ориентации.
Так вот,как при смене ориентации снова вызывать `LayoutManager` и т.д, ?
К примеру, высчитались кол-во столбцов в `GridAutofitLayoutManager` ?
пробовал так:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    Integer minWidth;
    minWidth = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.minItemWidht);
    Log.d("TAG ", String.valueOf(minWidth));

    layoutManager = new GridAutofitLayoutManager(context, minWidth);
     mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

}
```

Но не помогло. Во время дебага всё хорошо, `GridAutofitLayoutManager` высчитывает количество новых столбцов. Как только снимаешь точку остановку,перестаёт. Возможно времени не хватает?

[Здесь код GridAutofitLayoutManager](http://pastebin.com/c79SM4gP)

`totalSpice` как-то иногда неправильно высчитывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй кастомный RecyclerView (`public class AutofitRecyclerView extends RecyclerView`)
А в нем в методе onMeasure можно пересчитывать количество.

Такой код работает хорошо:

```
package сom.example;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class AutofitRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    int spanCount = 1;
    private GridLayoutManager manager;
    private int columnWidth = -1;

    public AutofitRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public AutofitRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutofitRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            int[] attrsArray = {
                    android.R.attr.columnWidth
            };
            TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
            columnWidth = array.getDimensionPixelSize(0, -1);
            array.recycle();
        }

        manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 5);
        manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch (getAdapter().getItemViewType(position)) {
                    case AppsAdapter.TYPE_HEADER:
                        return spanCount;
                    case AppsAdapter.TYPE_ITEM:
                        return 1;
                    default:
                        return 1;
                }
            }
        });
        setLayoutManager(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public GridLayoutManager getLayoutManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        if (columnWidth > 0) {
            spanCount = Math.max(1, getMeasuredWidth() / columnWidth);
            manager.setSpanCount(spanCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Помог мне

```
 mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    Integer minWidth;
                    minWidth = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.minItemWidht);
                    layoutManager = new GridAutofitLayoutManager(context, minWidth);
                    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    adapterRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Только размеры с ума сошли